# INSERT query not woking

Tags: java, postgresql, jsp

```
<body>
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Statement" %>
<%@ page import="javax.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager" %>
<%    
    String pwd = request.getParameter("pass");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");


        Statement st,stt = null;
        Connection con = null;
        int i=0;


    try {

    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://hostname","username", "Password");

    stt = con.createStatement();
    st = con.createStatement();


         ResultSet rs;  
         rs = stt.executeQuery("select * from users where email='"+email+"'");  

         if (!rs.next()) {

             ResultSet rss;
                 rss = st.executeQuery("insert into users(email,password) values ('"+email+"','"+pwd+"')");

              if(rss.next()) {  

                 response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
                 out.print("Registration Successfull!"+"<a href='index.jsp'>Go to Login</a>");

               }else {

                    response.sendRedirect("reg.jsp");
                    out.print("Registration was not Successfull!"+"<a href='reg.jsp'>Go to Registration</a>");
                   }

         }else {

             response.sendRedirect("reg.jsp?error=Email already exsist!");
         } 
       }catch (Exception e) {

           e.printStackTrace();
     }

%>
</body>
```

Comment: What isn't working , do you get an error ?

Comment: And don't use JSP for data access! At-least use servlets instead of JSP!

Comment: try using executeUpdate https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)

Comment: better to put java code in ``java``, not ``jsp``

Comment: I agree with the others: Do not put Java code like that into a JSP, but the retrieval logic into a servlet. And learn how to use a connection pool.

Comment: ... and how to avoid [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Did you by any chance time-travel from 1996 to 2017 to ask this question? JSP should be used for presentation and not data access, also do add some details around your code snippet to add context.

Answer (score 0):

Use `executeUpdate` for inserts, updates & delete,
`executeQuery` for select operations